# MacBook Pro keep on "unplugging" battery and need SMC/PRAM reset

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management, nvram

I recently brought my 2015 13" MacBook Pro to an Apple center to get a screen replacement for Staingate. They did it for free. Before this replacement my MacBook was doing really good actually.

After that, battery issues started. Sometimes MacBook doesn't boot-up or doesn't wake-up from sleep saying that battery is dead. That is not true obviously, when I get to that point I need to plug it to the MagSafe, or do a SMC reset, or if none of the previous work, a PRAM reset. Then it will work perfectly for a few hours (or days, randomly).

CoconutBattery states the battery has a good health but I noticed (before doing an SMC), that battery was disappearing and reappearing suddenly from battery, as if it doesn't exists. I did a few hardware checks at boot ant they always looked perfect but one time in which I got PPT001 error (battery not detected).

I can't get to have a permanent fix and I wanted to ask someone else before bringing it back to the Apple center as it's a bit far away from my home.

Comment: First port of call would be Apple ... "Since you changed my screen..."

Comment: That's exactly what I'm going to do if I don't get to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your charger might be dying.

I recently had to change the charger of an old MacBook, after experiencing very similar issues and eliminating all sorts of other possible problems. I even bought a new battery (yes, it was that old). I was about to give up on the device, thinking the motherboard was dead or something.

As a last resort I went to a local store and asked to try charging it with a new MagSafe charger. The device has been happily working again ever since.

Try doing the same; it's basically free to try if they have a relevant charger in stock.

Comment: How can it be the MagSafe if MacBook is already charged and charger it's unplugged and the issues show up??